# Proof that the function $k: (A^B)^C \mapsto A^{B \times C}$ is bijective and well-defined.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

This function is defined as $k(f): B \times C \rightarrow A: (b,c) \mapsto k(f)(b,c) = f(c)(b).$

I already proved that this function is injective and surjective. Thus, it is bijective. But I don't know how to show that the function $k$ is also well-defined. Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Showing a function is well-defined is essentially showing that it is a function, i.e., for every input $f$, $k$ sends $f$ to an element of the codomain.

Comment: I think that by 'well-defined' means that k is total (i.e. every element of the domain has an image) and functional (the same element cannot be mapped to different values). Is that correct? Are you able to show these two points?

Comment: $f$ should be in $C \to (A^B)$ but you say $f(b)(c)$ rather than $f(c)(b)$. $C$ is outermost so that goes first.

Comment: @AHusain Hmm I copied it from the excercise.

So what I have to do is actually is: if $f = g$, then $k(f) = k(g)$. And then assume that $f = g$? 
It looks like the other way around of showing something is injective.

Comment: Define the function $g$ as $g: B \times C \rightarrow A$ and $k(g)$ as $k(g): C \rightarrow A^B$. Since we assumed that $f=g$, we can also write  $f: B \times C \rightarrow A$. From here it follows that $\forall c \in C$ and $\forall b \in B$ that $k(g)(b)(c) \in A$. From the definition, we have $k(g)(b)(c) = g(b,c)$, and so $g(b,c) = f(b,c)$. Thus $k(f)=k(g)$. This means that $k$ is well-defined. Can somebody check if this is correct? Really appreciate it!

Comment: Edit: I mean $k(g)(c)(b)$ and $g(b,c) = f(c)(b)$

Comment: If it's not correct, I'm really stuck. I would appreciate it if a solution can be provided.

Comment: It's possible (although maybe not likely at this level) that they might be referring to the transformation being well-defined in terms of *extensional equality* of functions.  i.e. Maybe the foundational system does not consider $\lambda (n : \mathbb{N}) . n$ and $\lambda (n : \mathbb{N}) . (n + 0)$ to be literally the same function since they're written differently; but the two functions are extensionally equal since $f(n) = g(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  (And then, on the left-hand side, there's the complication that two functions in $(A^B)^C$ should be considered...

Comment: extensionally equal if for all $c \in C$, we have $f(c)$ and $g(c)$ are extensionally equal.  That then opens the possibility that we might want to allow $A, B, C$ to be setoids, i.e. sets with a given equivalence relation, instead of just sets with Leibniz equality; we restrict $A^B$ to the functions $B \to A$ which are well-defined with respect to the respective equivalence relations, and give it the setoid structure of extensional equality; etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There really isn't much to check here.  You have specified the value of $k(f)$ on each pair $(b,c)\in B\times C$, and thus defined a function $k(f)$ on $B\times C$.  I guess maybe they want you to check that the value $f(c)(b)$ which is defined for $k(f)(b,c)$ actually exists and is an element of $A$.  This is because $c\in C$ (so it is in the domain of $f$) and then $f(c)$ is a function $B\to A$ so $b$ is in its domain and the value $f(c)(b)$ is in $A$.  So, $k(f)$ is indeed a function $B\times C\to A$, and since you have defined this for each $f\in (A^B)^C$, $k$ is a function $(A^B)^C\to A^{B\times C}$.

(Usually, when people talk about checking that a function is "well-defined", that means its definition involved using some non-unique representation of its inputs and you want to check that the output you get is independent of the representation chosen.  There isn't anything like that going on here, though, so asking you to check the function is well-defined is a bit odd.)